# Access-Control-Allow-Origin does not match.. but it does

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, cors, ajax

Nginx CORS error is not going away.
I am using Debian Jessie and below is the and sites-available/reverse.conf
Reverse.conf is the file i created for reverse proxy.
I am getting this CORS error on login page.
I tried adding the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin and setting its value as * and the URL the request is going to.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

```
server {
listen 9090;

location / {
root /usr/share/nginx/html/Usecase3;
index index.html index.htm;
}
location /platform/security/admin/beta/login {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8090/platform/login;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://localhost:9090/platform/login;
}
}
```

Tried putting the URL in quotes,
Tried using '*' i.e. allow all,
but nothing is working out.

Error -

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:9090/platform/login. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not match 'null, http://localhost:9090/platform/login').

And why is the null keyword appearing above in the error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fix your application. It sends `null`

Comment: created a new application with very less commands, and it is not showing the null error now, instead it show - 
Request CORS header - Access-Control-Allow-Origin is missing

Comment: BTW, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` must not contain path. In your case it should be just `http://localhost:9090`

Comment: @AlexeyTen The problem still remains the same. Any other solution?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Directive [add_header](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) modifies the response. Try use [proxy_set_header](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header) to add the header to the request.

Comment: When using proxy_set_header it shows -
> Request CORS header - Access-Control-Allow-Origin is missing